# Is the following function considered type-stable in Julia?

Tags: julia, type-stability

I want to have a curried version of a function. So, I write the code as follows:

```
f(x::Int64, y::Int64) = x + y
f(x::Int64) = (y::Int64) -> f(x, y)
```

But I am not sure if Julia considers this an example of a type-unstable definition. On the face of it, one of the methods returns an anonymous function, while another returns an `Int64`. Yet, when the curried version is applied, the final result is also an `Int64`.

So, my questions are:

1. Is this code type-stable?
2. If not, is there a way to have a curried version of a function without writing type-unstable code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is.
According to the official doc, you can investigate it by using the [`@code_warntype`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/#man-code-warntype) macro:

```
julia> @code_warntype f(1, 5)
MethodInstance for f(::Int64, ::Int64)
  from f(x::Int64, y::Int64) in Main at REPL[2]:1
Arguments
  #self#::Core.Const(f)
  x::Int64
  y::Int64
Body::Int64
1 ─ %1 = (x + y)::Int64
└──      return %1
```

The arguments of this function have the exact type `Int64`, and as we can see in the `Body::Int64`, the inferred return type function is `Int64`.

Furthermore, we have `f(x)` which is based on the type-stable function `f(x, y)`:

```
julia> @code_warntype f(1)
MethodInstance for f(::Int64)
  from f(x::Int64) in Main at REPL[15]:1
Arguments
  #self#::Core.Const(f)
  x::Int64
Locals
  #3::var"#3#4"{Int64}
Body::var"#3#4"{Int64}
1 ─ %1 = Main.:(var"#3#4")::Core.Const(var"#3#4")
│   %2 = Core.typeof(x)::Core.Const(Int64)
│   %3 = Core.apply_type(%1, %2)::Core.Const(var"#3#4"{Int64})
│        (#3 = %new(%3, x))
└──      return #3
```

Here as well, there's not any unstable defined parameter type.
Look at the following as an example of an unstable-typed function:

```
julia> unstF(X) = x*5
unstF (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @code_warntype unstF(1)
MethodInstance for unstF(::Int64)
  from unstF(X) in Main at REPL[17]:1
Arguments
  #self#::Core.Const(unstF)
  X::Int64
Body::Any
1 ─ %1 = (Main.x * 5)::Any
└──      return %1
```

If you try this in the REPL, you'll see the `Any` appears with a red color. Since we have the `Body::Any` (`Any` with the red color), we can conclude that the returned object by this function is a non-concrete type object. Because the compiler doesn't know what is the `x` (Note that the input is `X`). So the result can be `Any`thing! So this function is type-unstable for (here, for integer inputs. Note that you should investigate the type-stability of your function by your desired input(s). E.g., `@code_warntype f(5)` and `@code_warntype f(5.)` should be observed if I can pass it `Float64` or `Int64` either).

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the macros!